# Using ASP.NET MVC 3.0 to display column labels when mousing over bar chart

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, charts

I've looked for a solution to this, and while I can see how to do it with Silverlight, I can't work it out for ASP.NET. I've generated a simple bar chart using Microsoft's Chart Tools, but there are a large number of columns added so the labels on the x axis are not clear, and only show for a few of the columns.

The code I've used to generate the chart is:

```
public ActionResult ChartUserTotals() {
    var data = new ArrayList {};
    foreach (var user in org.Users) {
        data.Add(new { X = user.FullName, Y = UserTotal });
    }
    new Chart(400, 300, ChartTheme.Blue)
                .AddTitle("User Totals")
                .DataBindTable(data, "X")
                .SetYAxis("Totals")
                .Write("png");
    return null;
}
```

And in my view:

```
<img src='@url.Action("ChartUserTotals", "Dashboard")' alt="User Totals"/>
```

Does anyone know how I can display the label values on column mouseover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I asked this ages ago, but I thought I should mention that the given answer (using the title attirbute) isn't what I was looking for (since the tooltip needs to differ depending on which column the user is hovering over), however I solved this a different way. I ended up using the jQuery plugin [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com) (which is a really easy, not to mention beautiful, jQuery plugin). Not hugely MVC friendly though, needed to push a C# array into javascript through Razor, but it did work. For anyone with a similar problem, this is what I'd reccommend

Comment: actually, this could be simpler - i believe its not too difficult to push json directly from asp.net to javascript. ive not done this, but if that is the case then this solution would be perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I simply use the Title attribute on the Html element.

```
<img alt="ToolTip" src="/PermitApplication/Content/images/information.png" title="Enter
the phone number using XXX-XXX-XXXX or (XXX) XXX-XXXX">
```

Seems to work in any modern browser.